# SQLI Query not Updating NULL

Tags: sql, database

I am having a problem with updating a NULL value in SQLI.

```
SELECT * FROM sqli_information;

UPDATE sqli_information
SET optional_security_question = "Not Available"
WHERE optional_security_question = NULL;
```

There are no errors but it just stays at null. I am trying to get every `NULL` value in the `optional_security_question` and turn it into `Not Available` instead.

Comment: `IS NULL`, not `= NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this syntax:

```
UPDATE sqli_information
SET optional_security_question = "Not Available"
WHERE optional_security_question IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I will make sure to mark this answer as correct when the cooldown ends. Have an amazing day/night!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing "WHERE optional_security_question = NULL;" to "WHERE optional_security_question **IS** NULL;" and see if that allows you to update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Someone else has answered to this first so I will correct their answer but this is still correct. Have a good day/night!